# Relating the automorphisms of $P$ and those of $P/Φ(P)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Below is part of an exercise in Section 6.1 of Abstract Algebra: Dummit and Foote.

> **26. (e)** Let $p$ be a prime. Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group. Let $\sigma$ be any automorphism of $P$ of prime order $q$ with $q\neq p$. Show that if $\sigma$ fixes the coset $xΦ(P)$ then $\sigma$ fixes some element of this coset (Hint: note that since $Φ(P)$ is characteristic in $P$ every automorphism of $P$ induces an automorphism of $P/Φ(P)$).

What actual use is of the hint? At first glance I thought that it is of no use and this is my thought process: $(*)-$ Suppose $\sigma$ fixes $xΦ(P)$, a coset of order $p^a$ for some $a$.  Since $|\sigma|=q$, its cycle decomposition as a permutation on elemenets of $P$ consists of $1$- and $q$-cycles only, i.e. an element is either fixed by $\sigma$, or is part of a $q$-cycle. So, we know that $\sigma$ must have a fixed point in $xΦ(P)$, since $q\nmid p^a$ implies there must be an element of $xΦ(P)$ not being part of any $q$-cycle. $-(*)$

Then I realized that this goes very wrong. I must be missing something since I didn't even use the hint! I'm guessing that the $\sigma$ that 'fixes the coset $xΦ(P)$' and the $\sigma$ that 'fixes some element of this coset' are actually two different things! So let's rename the former one, the one that 'fixes the coset $xΦ(P)$', as $\sigma_{ind}$. This may be what the authors actually have in mind: $$\sigma_{ind}:P/Φ(P)\rightarrow P/Φ(P)$$$$\sigma_{ind}(yΦ(P))=\sigma(y)Φ(P)$$ for all $y\in P$. $\sigma_{ind}\in\operatorname{Aut}(P/Φ(P))$ is said to be 'induced' by $\sigma$. It's a trivial task to check that $\sigma_{ind}$ is indeed an automorphism. The fact that $\sigma_{ind}$ is well-defined, i.e. the choice of coset representatives does not matter, results from $Φ(P)$ being a characteristic subgroup of $P$!

What's more: I found that if $\sigma_{ind}$ fixes the coset $xΦ(P)$ as an element of $P/Φ(P)$, then $\sigma$ also fixes $xΦ(P)$! Now $(*)$ finishes the proof.

Am I on the right track? Or do the authors actually mean another thing?

**P.S.** What's special about $Φ(P)$ here? Can it not be replaced by an arbitrary characteristic subgroup of $P$?

Comment: Your original proof looks OK to me. There is no obligation to use a hint.

Comment: @DerekHolt Would it be THAT simple? My point is that the two $\sigma$'s in the question may actually mean two different things. I think that is so because part (f) of this question actually asks why every nontrivial automorphism of $P$ of order prime to $p$ induces a nontrivial automorphism on $P/Φ(P)$.

Comment: I think you are being overcomplicated. The question that you have asked about makes perfect sense as it is, and your solution is correct. This part is used in the proof of (f), but you do not need the hint to prove (e). You need the hint for part (e) to make sense.

Comment: @DerekHolt Then what do you think is an 'induced automorphism'? How does an automorphism of $P$ 'induce' an automorphism on its quotient group $P/Φ(P)$? How do I need the hint for part (e) to make sense anyway?

Comment: If $\sigma  \in {\rm Aut}(P)$ then the automorphism of $P/\Phi(P)$ induced by $\sigma$ is defined by $\sigma(g\Phi(P)) = \sigma(g)\Phi(P)$. It is not hard to show that this map is well-defined (that is because $\sigma(\Phi(P)) = \Phi(P)$) and  is an automorphism of $P/\Phi(P)$. But you don't need any of that for (e), because there you are told that $\sigma(x\Phi(P)) = x\Phi(P)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $y\in\Phi\left(P\right)$, define $\sigma\cdot\left(xy\right)\equiv\sigma\left(xy\right)=\sigma\left(x\right)\sigma\left(y\right)$. The property $\Phi\left(P\right)\text{char}P$ implies $\sigma\left(y\right)\in\Phi\left(P\right)$ so, by hypothesis, $\sigma\left(x\right)\sigma\left(y\right)\in\sigma\left(x\right)\Phi\left(P\right)=x\Phi\left(P\right)$ which verifies that $\sigma\cdot\left(xy\right)$ is an action of $\left\langle\sigma\right\rangle$ on the elements of the coset $x\Phi\left(P\right)$.

Associated with the action is a homomorphism $\tau :\left\langle\sigma\right\rangle\rightarrow S_{\left|\Phi\left(P\right)\right|}$ and the image $\tau\left(\left\langle\sigma\right\rangle\right)$ is either $1$ or isomorphic to $\left\langle\sigma\right\rangle$. The result is immediate for image $1$ so consider image $\left\langle\sigma\right\rangle$. The orbits can have either length $1$ or $q$ and $q$ does not divide $p$ so there must be orbits of length $1$ (the orbits form a partition of the coset). Thus the result.