# Automorphisms of $P/Φ(P)$ induced by those of $P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Seriously, it's just a continuation of [Relating the automorphisms of $P$ and those of $P/Φ(P)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581784/relating-the-automorphisms-of-p-and-those-of-p-%CE%A6p), an exercise in Section 6.1 of Abstract Algebra: Dummit and Foote. A lot of typing:

I assume I had part **(e)** done and now I'm going to do part **(f)**.

> **26. (f)** Let $p$ be a prime. Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group. Use part **(e)** and **(c)** to deduce that every nontrivial automorphism of $P$ of order prime to $p$ induces a nontrivial automorphism on $P/Φ(P)$. Deduce that any group of automorphisms of $P$ which has order prime to $p$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(P/Φ(P))=GL_r(\Bbb F_p)$.

where $P/Φ(P)$ is just elementary abelian of order $p^r$.

> **(e)** Let $\sigma$ be any automorphism of $P$ of prime order $q$ with $q\neq p$. Show that if $\sigma$ fixes the coset $xΦ(P)$ then $\sigma$ fixes some element of this coset.
>
> **(c)** If $x_1Φ(P),x_2Φ(P),\dots,x_rΦ(P)$ are any basis for the $r$-dimensional vector space $P/Φ(P)$ over $\Bbb F_p$ and if $x_i$ is any element of the coset $x_iΦ(P)$, then $P=\langle x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r\rangle$...

At first, I had no idea what is being 'prime to $p$'. I assume it means 'relatively prime to $p$', instead of 'a prime relatively prime to $p$', which is same as 'a prime different from $p$'. Now down to business: I know how an automorphism $\sigma$ of $P$ induces an automorphism of $P/Φ(P)$: $$\sigma_{ind}:P/Φ(P)\rightarrow P/Φ(P)$$$$\sigma_{ind}(gΦ(P))=\sigma(g)Φ(P)$$ for all $g\in P$. $\sigma_{ind}$ is said to be induced by $\sigma$. Now the contrapositive of the first statement of **(f)**:

Suppose $\sigma_{ind}$ is trivial. I'm gonna show that either $\sigma$ is trivial, or $p\mid|\sigma|$.

Suppose by contradiction that $\sigma\neq1$ and $p\nmid|\sigma|$. Then we write $|\sigma|$ as product of primes. Suppose $|\sigma|$ is just a prime $q$ with $q\neq p$. Since $\sigma_{ind}$ fixes every element of $P/Φ(P)$, i.e., $gΦ(P)=\sigma(g)Φ(P)$ for all $g$, $\sigma$ fixes every coset of $Φ(P)$, as a result of $Φ(P)$ being a characteristic subgroup. So by **(e)**, every coset of $Φ(P)$ contains a fixed point of $\sigma$. Among those cosets, we can find a basis for $P/Φ(P)$. By **(c)**, we can choose an arbitrary representative from each of the cosets that form a basis and have the representatives generate $P$. **So we might as well just choose those fixed points!** So $P$ is generated by fixed points of $\sigma$! Contradicts to our assumption that $\sigma\neq1$.

Even if $|\sigma|$ is not a prime, that's fine. (I hope so) Every prime factor of $|\sigma|$ is not $p$. Choose one, say, $q$, and there must be some power of $\sigma$ of order $q$ (say $\sigma^{|\sigma|/q}$). i.e. $\sigma^{|\sigma|/q}$ is an automorphism of $P$ of order $q$ with $q\neq p$. Since $\sigma$ fixes every coset of $Φ(P)$, so does $\sigma^{|\sigma|/q}$. By similar arguments, $P$ is generated by fixed points of $\sigma^{|\sigma|/q}$, so $\sigma^{|\sigma|/q}=1$. So $|\sigma|\mid(|\sigma|/q)$, which is absurd.

**Questions:**

- Is this proof correct? I know it appears lengthy and I shouldn't have separated it into two cases when $|\sigma|$ is prime and when it's not, but is it correct?
- I have no idea about the second statement of **(f)**. Maybe if $\{\sigma_1,\dots\sigma_j\}$ is a group of automorphism of $P$, then it is isomorphic to $\{\sigma_{1_{ind}}\dots\sigma_{j_{ind}}\}$? Can somebody give me a hint at least?

Comment: Your proof for the first part looks OK. For the second part, suppose that $\sigma \in {\rm Aut}(P)$ induces $\bar{\sigma} \in {\rm Aut}(P/\Phi(P))$. Then you need to prove that the map $\sigma \mapsto \bar{\sigma}$ defines a homomorphism ${\rm Aut}(P) \to {\rm Aut}(P/\Phi(P))$, which should be straigthforward.

Comment: @DerekHolt Suppose $f$ is such homomorphism. $f:\sigma\rightarrow\sigma_{ind}$ for all $\sigma$. $f(\sigma_1\sigma_2)=(\sigma_1\sigma_2)_{ind}$. This maps $gΦ(P)$ to $\sigma_1\sigma_2(g)Φ(P)$. $f(\sigma_1)f(\sigma_2)=\sigma_{1_{ind}}\sigma_{2_{ind}}$. This maps $gΦ(P)$ to $\sigma_1(\sigma_2(g))Φ(P)$.

Comment: But what does any of these have to do with the order of the group of automorphisms being prime to $p$?

Comment: Let $A \le {\rm Aut}(P)$ with $\gcd(|A|,p)=1$. Then $f(A) \cong A$.